# Free tool capable of advanced multiple substitutions in non-Ascii documents (at least RTF)

Tags: windows, gratis, text-search, word-processor, rtf

As I am looking for a software capable of very simple thing, bulk search and replace, I expected to find one with ease. Alas, either my google-fu proved too weak, or my assumption was wrong. There is a ton of software for supposedly advanced search & replace, but it caters to programmers. It focuses on the sheer amounts of occurrences and the size of data operated on, but it's generally only for ASCII-compatible data. I don't need a tool to perform one simple substitution on a myriad of simple text files, I need a tool to perform a myriad of substitutions on one document. To be precise, I am looking for something that:

- can perform multiple, different substitutions in one action (e.g. replace all "cat" with "dog" AND all "horse" with "cow" in the single opened document)
- operates on common document formats (at least RTF) instead of ascii text files
- can save the set of actions for future use, so the user can just load&launch instead of defining dozens of substitutions again
- is freeware for Windows.

I know it all can be achieved with one of open-source word processor and set of macros, but I am looking for something more dedicated to this purpose. My target humans are stubborn. I can convince them to learn to use new program for new purpose ("from now on you will use this cutting edge dedicated tool to process your document once its ready") and they won't make a sound; but once they hear "open office/libre office" it doesn't matter what the rest of sentence is. They enter "my Word is better because I use it and I use it because it's better" mode and dismiss anything else I have to say. 
Does anybody know a tool for that, or bigger program capable of that?

Comment: Do you need to see the document to be processed or would something like "replacer.exe -i myDocument.rtf catToDog.repl horseToCow.repl" be okay?

Comment: Command line tool would be entirely sufficient. It's power I seek, not GUI. In this case, I guess power would equal to the number of document formats the tool would be able to operate on and maybe, I don't know,  substitutions defined with regular expressions? Though, a singlefile replacements list passed as a parameter would be more practical. It's the amount of the substitions that makes me seek new solutions, with two, as in example, I'd just press that ctrl G twice and be done with it :)

Comment: So, "non-ascii" imply the documents have structure.  There are lots of documents that have different structures (.doc, .xslx, .pdf, .rtf, ..xml, jison, latex, ...)  How do you imagine such a tool manages many different structures? Structures it has not encountered before? Or is that you just want to modify RTF files?

Comment: I am well aware of how different all these standards are. I can't imagine a tool managing unknown structures and obviously I don't. For all the known ones, the answer is obvious, a tool can manage all the input its author thought of and decided to write the code for. Come on, it was quite a jump from me writing about common documents to question about structures not encountered before. RTF is what I need now, but I imagined if such a tool existed, it'd also operate on more popular types, like .doc, .docx, .odt Though, lack of answer makes me worry it may actually not exist at the moment :/